# Center Panel's Component Within a java swing BoxLayout

Tags: java, swing, boxlayout

I'm trying to use a BoxLayout to display 2 panels vertically and I searched how to center the components in those panels. At the moment, my components are placed on the top center of each panel, and I want to get them at the center X and Y.

I added the components I want in the 2 panels, then I added the panels in my BoxLayout. This way they're displayed vertically as I want them to be, but as I said I don't want them to be on top center.

I tried to use methods such as setAlignementY and setLocation but any of them actually moves the components. I also saw that a BoxLayout will try to set the components as wide as the widest component, but as I have only 2 panels which have the same size I don't really understand it.

This is basically how I've added my components (without trying to center) :

```
private void initPanels ()
    {
        this.titlePanel.add(this.title);

        this.bookInputPanel.add(bookTitle);
        this.bookInputPanel.add(bookInput);

        this.authorInputPanel.add(by);
        this.authorInputPanel.add(authorInput);
        this.authorInputPanel.add(this.authorsTable);

        this.buttonsPanel.add(confirm);

        this.contentPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this.contentPanel,     BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        this.contentPanel.add(bookInputPanel);
        this.contentPanel.add(authorInputPanel);

        this.add(this.titlePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(this.contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(this.buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
```

I made a picture to show you exactly what I want but it seems that I need 10 rep to do it, sorry about that.

Comment: @3rdBattalion When editing questions, please don't add tags to the title. Stack Overflow has a separate tagging system for that.

Comment: @3rdBattalion Thank you for reviewing my question. As you probably see, English is not my mother tongue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This way they're displayed vertically as I want them to be, but as I said I don't want them to be on top center.

One way is to add "glue" to the top/bottom of the panel. This "glue" will expand to fill the extra space available to the panel:

```
this.contentPane.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
this.contentPanel.add(bookInputPanel);
this.contentPanel.add(authorInputPanel);
this.contentPane.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BoxLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) for more information about the feature of a `BoxLayout`.

Another option might be to use a "wrapper" panel that uses a different layout manager. For example the `GridBagLayout` with the default constraints will automatically center the component horizontally/vertically:

```
//this.add(this.contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
JPanel wrapper = new JPanel( new GridBagLayout() );
wrapper.add( contentPanel );
this.add(wrapper, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: Thanks @camickr this solved my problem. I added Glue before, after and between the two panels. All is perfectly centered now